# Oracle 11g SQL Error: ORA-00904: "CUST_ID": invalid identifier

Tags: oracle11g

I'm a newbie trying to setup some basic tables. I've already created a table names Customer with a primary key called Cust_ID and a table called City with PK called Zip_Code. When I try to create a table called Address and include these PK's as FK's I get the error below. Any help greatly appreciated as already tried several web solutions. Code and Error below. Thanks, Richard.

```
CREATE TABLE ADDRESS
( ADDR_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
Addr_Ln1 VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,    
Addr_Ln2 VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,    
CONSTRAINT ADDRESS_PK PRIMARY KEY (ADDR_ID),
 CONSTRAINT fk_customer FOREIGN KEY(Cust_ID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER (Cust_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT fk_city FOREIGN KEY (Zip_Code) REFERENCES CITY (Zip_Code) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

This gives the following error:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
CREATE TABLE ADDRESS
( ADDR_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
Addr_Ln1 VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,    
Addr_Ln2 VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,    
CONSTRAINT ADDRESS_PK PRIMARY KEY (ADDR_ID),
 CONSTRAINT fk_customer FOREIGN KEY(Cust_ID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER (Cust_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT fk_city FOREIGN KEY (Zip_Code) REFERENCES CITY (Zip_Code) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
Error at Command Line : 6 Column : 37
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "CUST_ID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: Your `address` table does not have a column name `cust_id` or `zip_code`. You only defined the columns `addr_id`, `addr_ln1`, `addr_ln2`.

Comment: Thanks very much  a_horse_with_no_name. How stupid of me. That fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your script as column "Cust_ID" noit exist in your create statement.
You created only three columns (ADDR_ID, Addr_Ln1, Addr_Ln2)